# compare two images by histogram and plotting in one figure

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, histogram

I want to compare two brain image using histogram an plot them or make two graph in one figure. How can i do that? I can make two histogram in two different figure but can not plot them in one as i am new in matlab...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the best way, since it will be hard to compare data. But to show 2 histograms, use `hold on` and change the colors of each to make it easier to one from the other. (But might need to change the transparency also). I used `bar` since `hist` does not support color directly in the call itself. So this is easier.

```
close all;
clear all;

x = -4:0.1:4;
y1 = randn(200,1);
[n,x] = hist(y1,x);
bar(x,n,'r');

hold on
y2 = randn(200,1);
[n,x] = hist(y2,x);
bar(x,n,'b');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intead of using `bar` in Nasser M. Abbasi's code, use `stem` and see if that helps.